# How to extract PHP array values and remove data

Tags: php

I have seen a bunch of ways, but none that seem to work.  My array data is coming back like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => RESULT=0
    [1] => RESPMSG=Approved
    [2] => SECURETOKEN=8cpcwfZhaH02qNlIoFEGZ1wO4
    [3] => SECURETOKENID=253cad735251571cebcea28e877f4fd7
```

I use this:

```
<?php echo  $response[2];?>
```

too get each out, that works.  But I need to remove “SECURETOKEN=” so im left with just the number strings.  I have been trying something like this with out success.

```
function test($response){  
    $secure_token = $response[1];  
    $secure_token = substr($secure_token, -25);  
    return $secure_token; 
}
```

Also Im putting end number into a form input “Value” field. Not that that matters, unless it does?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `preg_replace` regex.

Comment: You are using response[1], not response[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
$keyResponse = [];
foreach ($response as $item) {
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $item, 2);
    $keyResponse[$k] = $v;
}
```

Now you can easily access just the value part of each item based on the name:

```
echo $keyResponse['SECURETOKEN']; // output: 8cpcwfZhaH02qNlIoFEGZ1wO4
```

The advantage to this method is the code still works if the order of the items in `$response` changes

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  This worked great, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I get your secure token like this (tested):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'RESULT=0',
    'RESPMSG=Approved',
    'SECURETOKEN=8cpcwfZhaH02qNlIoFEGZ1wO4',
    'SECURETOKENID=253cad735251571cebcea28e877f4fd7'
);

$el = $arr[2];
$parts = explode('=', $el);
echo '#1 SECURETOKEN is ' . $parts[1];

// This break just for testing
echo '<br />';

// If you wanted to, you could revise the whole array
$new = array();
foreach( $arr as $el ){
    $parts = explode('=', $el);
    $new[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
}

// Which would mean you could then get your securetoken like this:
echo '#2 SECURETOKEN is ' . $new['SECURETOKEN'];
```